# Replace GridLayout with LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I have a `GridLayout` that displays a calculator screen. It looks very nice on many devices but utterly fails on small displays and even some big displays. There is a [bug in GridLayout implementation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37108515) but Google is not working on it. You can see details in my half year old question and an accepted answer: [GridLayout collapses on small display](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42173015/1639556)

I tried to reimplement my layout. I started with new `ConstraintLayout` without luck. `LinearLayout` is quite close but I failed to stretch individual cells. They do not fill the available space. When I change a width from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`, the layout breaks totally.

All source code and a sample application is available at https://github.com/literakl/CalcTrouble.

Current Linear Layout

[image]

GridLayout when it works

[image]

Broken GridLayout on Nexus 5

[image]

Broken GridLayout on Nexus S

[image]

**Layout source code**

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/calc_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/bg_calc"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!--Display row-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/assignment"
    android:text="50 + 40 = 90"
    style="@style/Formula"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_display_height"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- row with 7-9,+ -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit7"
        android:text="7"
        style="@style/KeypadLeftButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit8"
        android:text="8"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit9"
        android:text="9"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
        android:text="+"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionRightButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--row with 4-6, - -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit4"
        android:text="4"
        style="@style/KeypadLeftButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit5"
        android:text="5"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit6"
        android:text="6"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
        android:text="-"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionRightButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--row with 1-3, * -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit1"
        android:text="1"
        style="@style/KeypadLeftButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit2"
        android:text="2"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit3"
        android:text="3"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
        android:text="\u22C5"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionRightButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--row with 0, backspace and / -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit0"
        android:text="0"
        style="@style/KeypadLeftButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBackspace"
        android:text="←"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
        android:text=":"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionRightButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<!--row with button submit -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
    android:text="@string/action_next_formula"
    style="@style/KeypadNextButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_next_height"
    app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I achieve desired look that will work on all devices?

Comment: how about using a nested linear layout? parent linear layout with vertical orinetation and nested liner layouts with weight = 1 & height=0. buttons inside Inner linear layout should have equal weight with width = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your button's `width` to `0dp`, `height` to `match_parent` and `layout_weight` to `1` as in below sample for a single row

```
    <!-- row with 7-9,+ -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum ="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit7"
        android:text="7"
        style="@style/KeypadLeftButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit8"
        android:text="8"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/digit9"
        android:text="9"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
        android:text="+"
        style="@style/KeypadFunctionRightButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: May I have a question? The bottom button is not displayed :-(

Comment: I have just put the button inside the LinearLayout and it is ok now

Answer (score 1):

Using ConstraintLayouts you can achieve this :

[image]

Layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_top"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_bottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_top">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_row"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/second_row"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_first_first"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button_first_second"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_first_second"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_first_first"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button_first_third"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_first_third"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_first_second"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button_first_fourth"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_first_fourth"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_first_third"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_row"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/third_row"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first_row">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_second_first"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button_second_second"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_second_second"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_second_first"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button_second_third"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_second_third"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_second_second"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button_second_fourth"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_second_fourth"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_second_third"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/third_row"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fouth_row"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/second_row">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_third_first"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button_third_second"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_third_second"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_third_first"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button_third_third"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_third_third"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_third_second"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button_third_fourth"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_third_fourth"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_third_third"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/fouth_row"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/third_row">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_fourth_first"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button_fourth_second"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_fourth_second"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_fourth_first"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button_fourth_third"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_fourth_third"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_fourth_second"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, i will give you try